# Scraping with Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, screen-scraping, simple-html-dom

Hi I am trying to scrape the UFC events schedule with Simple HTML DOM Parser.

I am struggling to select the right data.

i want the Title, Image, Date, Time & Location.

So far i have tried

```
function scraping_ufc() {
    // create HTML DOM
    $html = file_get_html('http://uk.ufc.com/schedule/event/');

    // get news block
    foreach($html->find('table tr') as $event) {
        // get title
        $item['title'] = trim($event->find('div[class="event-tagline"]', 0)->innertext);
        // get details
        $item['date'] = trim($event->find('div[class="date"]', 0)->innertext);

        $item['time'] = trim($event->find('div[class="time"]', 0)->innertext);

        $ret[] = $item;
    }


    // clean up memory
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

    return $ret;
}
```

Alot of not needed table rows are selected, i do manage to get the title but not the date or time.

Please help me select the data i need efficiently.

Comment: well as it breaches he sites Terms of Use, don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, stop using simple html dom because it's less reliable than the built-in dom library. It was useful some years ago but these days it really just causes more problems than it solves.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://uk.ufc.com/schedule/event/');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
```

Next, you need a better way to identify the rows you want. `table tr` will select every tr on the page and you don't want that. It would be nice if the tr's were styled but they're not so I came up with this:

```
foreach($xpath->query('//td[@class="upcoming-events-image"]/..') as $tr){
  $item['title'] = $xpath->query('.//div[@class="event-tagline"]/a', $tr)->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item['date'] = $xpath->query('.//div[@class="date"]', $tr)->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item['time'] = $xpath->query('.//div[@class="time"]', $tr)->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $ret[] = $item;
}
```